# Having troubles opening relative URL in Javascript xmlhttp object

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, ajax

I've inherited an HTML/PHP/Javascript application that is not broken up in specific directories; meaning, everything was in one directory.

I want to clean up and modularize the directory structure, so, I moved everything.
(*.inc files moved to the "Includes" folder, *.css files moved to the "CSS" folder, etc.)
Naturally, there is some changes to the code to be made.

I was making a (Working) AJAX request like this:

```
xmlhttp.open("GET","oWin.php?name="+escape(name)+"&type="+ct,true);
```

where "oWin.php" resided in the same directory as the calling page.  oWin.php is now located two directories up in the "Lib" folder.  So, I needed to change it to this:

```
xmlhttp.open("GET","../../Lib/oWin.php?name="+escape(name)+"&type="+ct,true);
```

but, sadly, this does not work; I get a "Syntax Error" logged to the web console in FireFox.

Can someone shed some light on this as to why it is a syntax error?

FireFox version 30.0 
Windows version 7, 64 bit
Apache 2.2.4, Win32
PHP 5.2.3

Thanks!

Keith

**UPDATE**
I've moved the oWin.php file into the same directory as the calling script and I am STILL getting a syntax error!  There MUST be some kind of error being returned from oWin.php....I will update as I discover more!

**UPDATE AND ANSWER**
Since I can't answer my own question yet (not 8 hours later and I'm a noob here)  :(

The REAL reason I was getting an error was not because of a syntax error in the Ajax call, but rather, what was getting PASSED back from oWin.php to the Ajax call.

I installed FireBug addon to help (I should have done that sooner) and had a look at the xml response.

I had PHP warnings enabled and was receiving a warning (didn't realize it) and so the PHP warning was getting passed to the Javascript interpreter via the AJAX call....so, naturally, the JS interpreter is going to throw an error!

Sorry for the noob mistake!

Thanks to everyone who read and responded!

Keith

Comment: ```xmlhttp.open``` is javascript. The ```../../``` type syntax if for *nix file dir system. Try hard coding the path of the site root like

```xmlhttp.open("GET","/path/to/Lib/oWin.php?name="+escape(name)+"&type="+ct,true);```

Let me know.

Comment: Hi datamafia!  Thanks for commenting.  I think I resolved my issue.  I had PHP warnings enabled and was receiveing a warning (didn't realize it) and so the PHP warning was getting passed to the Javascript interpreter via the AJAX call....so, naturally, the JS interpreter is going to throw an error!  Thanks Again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The REAL reason I was getting an error was not because of a syntax error in the Ajax call, but rather, what was getting PASSED back from oWin.php to the Ajax call.

I installed FireBug addon to help (I should have done that sooner) and had a look at the xml response.

I had PHP warnings enabled and was receiving a warning (didn't realize it) and so the PHP warning was getting passed to the Javascript interpreter via the AJAX call....so, naturally, the JS interpreter is going to throw an error!

Sorry for the noob mistake!

Thanks to everyone who read and responded!

Keith